# Как через Javascript заменить не тело, а конкретный тег?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Хочу через Google Tag Manager средствами javascript подменять в html строчке

```
<div class="map-container" id="map-container" style="display: none;">
```

cтрочку `display: none;`  на  `display: block;`

Нашел скрипт, который меняет текст в теле тега (например текст в середине тега h1)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById(“map-container”).innerHTML=”{{podmeniZag}}”;
</script>
```

Где "map-container" - это id элемента, а "podmeniZag" - это переменная, в которой подставляется значение (из таблицы)

Вопрос: Подскажите, как правильно указать, чтобы подмена переменной происходила именно в атрибуте style?

Comment: Точно так же `document.getElementById(“map-container”).style.display = 'block'`